# Compile time type checking with branching logic

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, compile-time

I'm trying to determine if there is a way, at compile time, to do a condition check on two different types at the same time.

Example:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
    returnVal myFunction() const
    {
        // Is there a compile time way of doing this?  std::conditional?
        return myConditionFunction(std::is_same<char, T> || std::is_same<unsigned char, T>);
    }

    returnVal myConditionFunction(std::true_type& const) const
    {
        // perform calculations on char or unsigned char
    }

    returnVal myConditionFunction(std::false_type& const) const
    {
        // perform calculations on non-char/unsigned char types
    }
};
```

I want to call a function if the type is a char or unsigned char.

Edit: Updated code to show I'm using a templated class.

Comment: What you are currently doing already is a compile time thing.

Comment: But (std::is_same<char, T> || std::is_same<unsigned char, T>) doesn't work.  I can do one or the other, but not both at same time.

Comment: How about a template for char and unsigned char that you specialize?.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the conditions to generate a compile time constant, and that to create a type that will match either `true_type` or `false_type`:

```
returnVal myFunction() const
{
   typedef std::integral_constant<bool, 
                                  std::is_same<unsigned char, T>::value
                               || std::is_same<         char, T>::value> selector;

   return myConditionFunction(selector());
}
```

Note that `std::true_type` is just `std::integral_constant<bool,true>` and similarly for `std::false_type`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do what you want. If you don't want to write any new templates yourself, you could do something like this (pseudocode, since `returnVal` isn't specified, and `T` isn't specified or deduced from anywhere):

```
#include <type_traits>

returnVal myFunction() const
{
    return myConditionFunction(
        typename std::is_same<unsigned char, typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>::type());
}

returnVal myConditionFunction(std::true_type& const) const
{
}

returnVal myConditionFunction(std::false_type& const) const
{
}
```

This uses the `std::make_unsigned` metafunction from the type traits library to convert `T` to whatever its unsigned counterpart is (so, if `T` is `char` or `unsigned char`, `std::make_unsigned<T>::type` will be `unsigned char`). Then, `std::is_same`'s result is used to dispatch to the appropriate function implementation.

Alternatively, you could write your own trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_char_or_uchar 
{ 
    typedef false_type type; 
    static const bool value = false;
}

template<>
struct is_char_or_uchar<char>
{
    typedef true_type type;
    static const bool value = true;
}

template<>
struct is_char_or_uchar<signed char>
{
    typedef true_type type;
    static const bool value = true;
}

template<>
struct is_char_or_uchar<unsigned char>
{
    typedef true_type type;
    static const bool value = true;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
returnVal myFunction() const
{
    return myConditionFunction(typename is_char_or_uchar<T>::type());
}

returnVal myConditionFunction(std::true_type& const) const
{
}

returnVal myConditionFunction(std::false_type& const) const
{
}
```

Alternatively, if you have Boost, you could use [`boost::mpl::or_`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/or.html) and two invocations to `std::is_same`.

Comment: Quick attempt at first option, I get compile errors as I am using templates, I need to guarantee type T is not boolean before using std::make_unsigned<T>().